# How to prevent onReceivedSslError

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

(My Eco system is Win10, Studio 4.5, Titanium SDK 5.2.2.GA)

After uploading my APK to Google i receive a security warning regarding
WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError: my implementation is ignoring SSL certificate validation an i am supposed to use SslErrorHandler.proceed()  or SslErrorHandler.cancel().

This is rather strage.

1) I do use Ti.Network.createHTTPClient to retrieve data from a website, but this is not a https url

2) In every net Ti.Network.createHTTPClient i use validatesSecureCertificate:true  (but without it i also get that warning)
(And AFAIK if you ommit this value, then it is automatically set to true when you package your app)

3) WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError  suggest something going on with a webview.... but my app does not make use of a webview. I do however use a createImageView... but that image also does not come from a https resource...
And AFAIK there is no property / method related to SSL...

4) I am using AdMob (2.2) and suspected that as source of the error. But after removing AdMob completely... i still received that warning...

So i am puzzled. Am i missing something? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue reported under:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3525

Please leave your contacts there and we'll get it fixed asap.